# xcode4.2 refuses to use IPad 2 with IOS 4.3.3 for development

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, itunes

Xcode4.2 refuses to use IPad 2 with IOS 4.3.3 for development,
Xcode Orginzer tells me software image is not available

what should i do help pleas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem , i only had to synchronize the ipad apps with my iTunes and restarting then  just worked